# Facebook SDK photo sharing to wall from Android app - Dialog not show

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I think my code is correct (mostly), as I have followed the [Facebook SDK guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) as closely as I could. But when I click the spinner in my ActionBar, I do not see the share dialog appear from the Facebook SDK. Nothing happens, no errors, just nothing.

I have everything required in my Manifest (the provider and the Facebook activity with my special number, also internet permissions). Also I read you do not need wall-access permissions anymore with the newer SDK, so I didn't include that in my code (nor did the guide mention it). I definitely must use the Facebook SDK though, and not an image-sharing-to-Facebook hack, as it's important for my resume. I simply want to share a bitmap photo to my wall in Facebook. Every similar problem on Stack has not helped.

Does anyone with experience with the current Facebook SDK see anything wrong in my code? Thanks.

```
package org.azure_simbiosys.cutecollection.phototab;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.share.model.SharePhoto;
import com.facebook.share.model.SharePhotoContent;
import com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog;

import org.azure_simbiosys.R;

public class PhotoViewerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Spinner shareSpinner;
    String[] shareList = {"Share", "Facebook", "Twitter", "SMS"};
    Bitmap bm;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    ShareDialog shareDialog;

    Integer[] iconList = {R.drawable.ic_action_social_share, R.drawable.ic_facebook,
            R.drawable.ic_twitter, R.drawable.ic_sms};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_viewer);

        // Shows the up carat near app icon in ActionBar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        ImageView photoView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo_display);

        // gets the single bitmap image from the array of bytes
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("photo");
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

        // sets device orientation based on the image orientation
        if (bm.getWidth() > bm.getHeight()){
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        } else
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        // sets bitmap into your ImageView
        photoView.setImageBitmap(bm);

        // set up Facebook photo sharing
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        shareDialog = new ShareDialog(PhotoViewerActivity.this);

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView iconTitle;
        ImageView iconImage;
    }


    public class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        int groupId;
        String[] textData;
        Activity context;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public SpinnerAdapter(Activity context, int vg, int id, String[] textData) {
            super(context, id, textData);
            this.context = context;
            groupId = vg;
            this.textData = textData;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService
                    (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return getView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View itemView = convertView;
            ViewHolder viewHolder;

            if(convertView == null) {
                itemView = inflater.inflate(groupId, parent, false);

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.iconImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerImage);

                viewHolder.iconTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview);

                itemView.setTag(viewHolder);

            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) itemView.getTag();
            }

            viewHolder.iconImage.setImageResource(iconList[position]);
            viewHolder.iconTitle.setText(textData[position]);

            return itemView;
        }
    }

    // callback for facebook sharing
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_share, menu);

        shareSpinner = (Spinner) menu.findItem(R.id.action_social_share).getActionView();
        SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.share_spinner_row,
                                                                R.id.textview, shareList);
        shareSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        // when share icon is clicked, set listener for the rows in the spinner
        shareSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                switch (position) {
                    case 1: // Facebook
                        Bitmap image = bm;
                        ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(PhotoViewerActivity.this);
                        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                                .setBitmap(image)
                                .build();
                        SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                                .addPhoto(photo)
                                .build();

                        shareDialog.show(content, ShareDialog.Mode.AUTOMATIC);

                        break;
                    case 2: // Twitter
                        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Twitter!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case 3: // SMS
                        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "SMS!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

               // don't need anything here for purposes of this app
            }
        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Makes the UP caret go back to the previous fragment MakeCuteHome
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                fm.popBackStack();
                finish();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use intent to post pics to facebook. i this way is long for sharing only pics. you should use direct intent. that will work fine instead of facebook sdk.

Comment: Do you have the Facebook app installed on device? Sharing of bitmaps is only supported via the native share dialog, which needs the Facebook app. You should wrap your calls to ShareDialog.share with a canShare() check.

Comment: @Ming, yes I do have the Facebook app installed. It should work, but it's not. :/

Comment: @Aiyaz, thanks but I really need to get the SDK to work.

Comment: what version of the Facebook app do you have?

Comment: @Ming, I have the version 34.00.43.267.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious. Have you tried some of the sample apps that ship with the SDK? If those work, and yours doesn't, consider filing a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs with a reproducible sample, and one of our partner engineers will have a look.

Comment: Just one question, Ming... at one point in the guide, it says to "work some code into the model", meaning the Sharing model. I did not know what they meant, so I just used the sharing code they offered (as shown above). Could that have been anything to look out for (to your knowledge)?

Comment: @Ming, I found a sample in the Facebook SDK called HelloFacebookSample that has a simple photo sharing button. But, like everything in the Facebook docs, getting it to work in my app is not happening. Getting a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.ipc.composer.intent.ComposerConfiguration` error and I don't even know what ComposerConfiguration is referring to. Why are these docs not more straight forward? Any ideas you have would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That's a class internal to the Facebook app and is not related to the SDK at all. Like I said, the best path forward is to build a simple reproducible app, and file a bug at the bugs page I linked to above.

Comment: Okay thanks good to know. I am copying code from the HelloFacebookSample, but it's still not working, so I'll file a bug report, thanks.